# Depassing 15V on Operational Amplificator?

Tags: feedback

So in the book it says we can obtain the following relation using negative feedback

(Out Voltage)=1+ R2/R1  (In Voltage)

The out voltage can depass +15 V , How can this be possible?

Comment: This wont happen. Before the output reaches the supply voltage, the op-amp would saturate, giving you rectangular waves.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm assuming you mean "exceed" instead of "depass"? The latter isn't a word in common English use.

The voltage relation shown is for a non-inverting op amp (yes, using negative feedback). The  output is always limited by the supply voltage; often to a value just a bit below the supply voltage. The supply, however, could be 30V (if allowed by the op amp selected).